# J8583: ISO8583 MessageFactory has no parsing guide for message type 0800

Tags: java, iso8583, j8583

I am using j8583 iso parser for ISO message (0800 2020000000800000 000000 000001 3239313130303031).

**Below is my java code:**

```
public class ISOUtility {

    private static BufferedReader reader;

    private static String getMessage() throws IOException {
        if (reader == null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }
     //   System.out.println("Paste your ISO8583 message here (no ISO headers): ");
        return "0800 2020000000800000 000000 000001 3239313130303031";
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        final MessageFactory<IsoMessage> mf = new MessageFactory<IsoMessage>();

       if (1 == 0) {


        //  ConfigParser.createFromClasspathConfig("j8583.xml");
            ConfigParser.configureFromDefault(mf);


        }  else {

            String path="C:\\Users\\DELL\\workspace\\SolabParser\\j8583.xml";
            if (System.console() != null) {
                System.console().printf("Attempting to configure MessageFactory from %s...%n", path);

            }
            System.out.println("Messagefactory is done");
            String url = "j8583.xml";
            if (path.contains("://")) {
                System.out.println("else ");

                ConfigParser.configureFromUrl(mf, new URL(path));
            } else {
                System.out.println("else ");
                ConfigParser.configureFromUrl(mf, new File(path).toURI().toURL());
            }
        }
        //Now read messages in a loop
        String line = getMessage();
        while (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
            IsoMessage m = mf.parseMessage(line.getBytes(), 14);
            if (m != null) {
                System.out.printf("Message type: %04x%n", m.getType());
                System.out.println("FIELD TYPE    VALUE");
                for (int i = 2; i <= 128; i++) {
                    IsoValue<?> f = m.getField(i);
                    if (f != null) {
                        System.out.printf("%5d %-6s [", i, f.getType());
                        System.out.print(f.toString());
                        System.out.println(']');
                    }
                }
            }
            line = getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is config file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE j8583-config PUBLIC "-//J8583//DTD CONFIG 1.0//EN"
    "http://j8583.sourceforge.net/j8583.dtd">
<j8583-config>
<!-- This is a test config file -->

<!-- These are the ISO headers to be prepended to the message types specified -->
<header type="0800"></header>

<template type="0280">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="2">99</field>
</template>

<!-- The server example uses this to read the requests -->
<parse type="0200">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="4" type="AMOUNT" />
    <field num="7" type="DATE10" />
    <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="12" type="TIME" />
    <field num="13" type="DATE4" />
    <field num="15" type="DATE4" />
    <field num="17" type="DATE_EXP" />
    <field num="32" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="35" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="37" type="NUMERIC" length="12" />
    <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="16" />
    <field num="43" type="ALPHA" length="40" />
    <field num="48" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="49" type="ALPHA" length="3" />
    <field num="60" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="61" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="100" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="102" type="LLVAR" />
</parse>

<!-- The client example uses this to read the responses -->
<parse type="0210">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="4" type="AMOUNT" />
    <field num="7" type="DATE10" />
    <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="12" type="TIME" />
    <field num="13" type="DATE4" />
    <field num="15" type="DATE4" />
    <field num="17" type="DATE_EXP" />
    <field num="32" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="35" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="37" type="NUMERIC" length="12" />
    <field num="38" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="39" type="NUMERIC" length="2" />
    <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="16" />
    <field num="43" type="ALPHA" length="40" />
    <field num="48" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="49" type="ALPHA" length="3" />
    <field num="60" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="61" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="70" type="ALPHA" length="3" />
    <field num="90" type="ALPHA" length="42" />
    <field num="100" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="102" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="126" type="LLLVAR" />
</parse>

<!-- this is for binary tests (message encoding AND fields) -->
<parse type="0600">
    <field num="4" type="AMOUNT" />
    <field num="7" type="DATE10" />
    <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="41" type="BINARY" length="8" />
    <field num="42" type="BINARY" length="4" />
    <field num="43" type="ALPHA" length="40" />
    <field num="62" type="LLBIN" />
    <field num="63" type="LLBIN" />
    <field num="64" type="LLLBIN" />
    <field num="65" type="LLLBIN" />
    <field num="102" type="LLLVAR" />
</parse>

<parse type="0800">
    <field num="3" type="ALPHA" length="6"/>
    <field num="12" type="DATE4" legth="14">
    <field num="17" type="DATE4" length="8"/>
    <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6"/>
    <field num="41" type="LLVAR" length="16"/>
</parse>

<parse type="0810" extends="0800">
    <field num="17" type="exclude"/>
    <field num="39" type="ALPHA" length="2"/>
</parse>

<parse type="0201">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="19" />
</parse>
<parse type="0202">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="22" />
</parse>
<parse type="0280">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="2" />
</parse>

</j8583-config>
```

I am using the message of type "0800" for which I am not using any header.

I am getting an error while compiling program: 
**ISO8583 MessageFactory has no parsing guide for message type 0800**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you're not using headers for 0800, you can omit that `header` entry. You obviously have a parsing guide for 0800, so perhaps you're not reading _that_ config file?

Answer (score 1):

on field number 12 change the spellings of the word length and close that tag with a slash, it lacks a closing slash.

```html
<field num="12" type="DATE4" length="14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did mistake with Field 41 format.
It is different in your profile for different message types.

Here is possible interpretation of your sample message where BIT 41 is 16 HEX chars converted to 8 ASCII letters(numbers).

https://iso8583.info/cmd/CB/AUTO/msg?080020200000008000000000000000013239313130303031

```
---
# Cheef's parser.
# Copyright (C) 2008-2016 Alexander Shevelev. https://iso8583.info/
# lib   : "/lib/CB/AUTO/" - CB2A Autorisation
# tool  : "msg"
# stat  : 10 nodes, 4 lookup tables, 100.00% passed (4/4)

msg:#"080020200000008000000000000000013239313130303031" # CB2A Autorisation message
- MTI: "0800" # Message Type ID. // Network management request
- DE000: "2020000000800000" # Primary bitmap // 3.11.41.
- BM0:#"0000000000013239313130303031" # Fields at Primary Bitmap
  - DE003:#"000000" # PC
    - S01: "00" # Transaction Code. // Purchase of goods or services
    - S02: "00" # Account, from. // Standard purchase
    - S03: "00" # Account, to. // Standard purchase
  - DE011: "000001" # STAN. // 1
  - DE041: "29110001" # CATI.

# run:0.030
```